# Is cloudfront or the global accelerator using private link?

Tags: aws-private-link

When connecting to cloudfront or to the global accelarator, is then amazon just using their private network, but is this network the same technology, that is used when vpc endpoints are used between VPC's?

Comment: When you say "private link" are you referring to AWS PrivateLink technology? https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/